# MarionetteJS version

Tags: javascript, marionette

Is there a way to get MarionetteJS version at runtime?

By runtime I mean something along the lines of

```
 
console.log(Backbone.VERSION);
 // or 
console.log(_.VERSION);
 // or 
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery); // well, this is a weird one...
```

I searched the API but couldn't find anything of the sort

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code](http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.js) and search for the version number (1.0.2), the only occurrence is in a comment at the top of the file.

So it looks like the version number is not available in MarionetteJS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a global variable for that:

```
Marionette.VERSION // "2.0.3"
```

Comment: Ok. Finally it got there...  ;-)